# Query on custom metadata field?

Tags: mysql, perl

This is a request from my client to tweak an existing Perl script. However, it is the actual database structure on their end that confuses me.

The requirement looks pretty simple:

```
only pull records where _X begins with 1, 2, or 9.
```

However, the underlying database is not that simple, here is the guideline from their DBA:

"_X is a custom metadata field. The database stores this data in rows, not columns, within the customData table. In order to query the custom data table in an efficient manner you need to know the Field_ID for the custom field you get that from the fielddef table:

```
SELECT Field_ID FROM FieldDef WHERE Name = "_X";

   This returns:
   10012
```

"Now you can query CustomData. For example:

```
SELECT Record_ID FROM CustomData where Field_ID="10012" AND StringValue="2012-04";
```

He also suggests that in my case, probably it would be:

```
"SELECT Record_ID FROM CustomData where Field_ID="10012" AND (StringValue LIKE '1%' || StringValue LIKE '2%' || StringValue LIKE '9%')
```

The weird thing is that the existing Perl script doesn't contain anything like "Select Record_ID FROM" but all like "SELECT StringValue FROM".

So that is why I am very confused here: What is "store in rows, not in columns"? Why first query the Field_ID table then CustomData? I would not be able to communicate with any of them during this weekend but really wish to get some idea on the whole thing, hope experts can help me a little on sorting out the whole structure.

More info(Table schema):

http://pastebin.com/ZiDTCCC0

The existing perl script:(focus on lines 72-136)

http://pastebin.com/JHpikTeZ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need a bit more information then.. can you show the table definitions, and what data the perl script does use.

Comment: sure, I will paste both into pastbin then update the question.

Comment: Holy ** that is some terrible EAV :P How does that perform? Ouch!

Comment: How is that even supposed to work? They do `$EditionAddedElectronic->execute();` but never fetch it, and later compare the statement against that metadata array.

Comment: Also, it's very nice that he uses prepared statements in his Perl code, but he just injects the strings in the statement. Kinda defeats the point. The values should be in the execute(...) statement.

Comment: really no idea, some other developer had developed this

Answer (score 1):

What they seem to be using is some kind of [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model, with the entities stored as ints and explained in another table (FieldDef).

You explained pretty well how you queried it (although you can do it in one query, with a join or a subquery), and your problem seems to be that you don't know how the Perl script does it. Unfortunately, without us seeing the Perl script, we can't either :]